# Wiki functionality with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, diff

What are the best plugins or gems to create a wiki functionality with rails ?

1. How to maintain versions ?
2. How to show html difference between
   two version ?

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a wiki site which uses [vestal_versions](https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions) for versioning and this cool javascript [diff](http://blog.lotusnotes.be/domino/archive/2007-10-29-js-diff.html) for highlighting changes, similar to stack overflow. It works fine and was really simple to set up. By escaping html tags before diff'ing you can output changes to html tags and also display inserted javascript.

Comment: I am using vestal_versions as you have mentions but I have one more quesiton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778088/how-to-insert-user-id-user-name-user-type-with-vestal-versions

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to build it yourself, you could just use Instiki:

http://instiki.org/show/HomePage

And even if you do want to build it yourself, the source is a good resource to answer your questions:

https://github.com/parasew/instiki

Answer (score 0):

In looking for other ruby/rails wikis I also found http://www.wagn.org/