# Looking for a good wiki platform for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wiki

I'm looking for a good wiki platform to work with RoR, I know mediawiki is great but its in PHP and I'd rather keep my code base in the same language if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wiki functionality with rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753298/wiki-functionality-with-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are list of wiki software written in Ruby and in other languages as well.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software#Ruby-based

Comment: That link doesn't work: the page has nothing on it that is Ruby-based.  In fact searching for "ruby" on that page yields no results (at least at the time I'm writing this).

Answer (score 4):

DHH (I think) wrote a simple wiki in Ruby several years ago called Instiki.  I haven't used it in a while, but I'm sure the code is out there somewhere.

If you want an active project, there's something called *Decko,* which is a wiki in Ruby, but an unusual (and apparently successful) take on how to do a wiki.  I've not used it, but all my poking at it suggests it's a very well-thought-out and useful approach.  Find it at https://decko.org/

Comment: Wagn is now Decko, and still going strong after 8 years. https://github.com/decko-commons/decko

Answer (score 1):

Try the font of gem-ishness, ruby-toolbox.com

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/wiki_apps

I note the top 3 are all git-baseed, rather than database based, at time of writing.
I've used none, myself yet. So I guess we use number of download be a guide?